# What leads to ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, iterator, concurrentmodification

I was reading about ConcurrentModificationException. I found this piece of code for the iterator.Can anybody explain what actually leads to this exception.I just want some justification for the logic written below.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public E next() {
    checkForComodification();
    int i = cursor;
    if (i >= size)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    cursor = i + 1;
    return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
}

public void remove() {
    if (lastRet < 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    checkForComodification();

    try {
        ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
        cursor = lastRet;
        lastRet = -1;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}

final void checkForComodification() {
    if (modCount != expectedModCount)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any specific problems? "There is some code out there that I don't understand" is not a problem, it's a fact, simply because there is much more code that anyone can comprehend in their entire life. This particular piece of code looks fine, at least at the first glance.

Comment: Absolutely, the code looks fine.But i couldn't understand the lines:

 Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your underlying number of elements are changing size while you are iterating over them so an exception is thrown.

Note that the attempt here isn't to recover from an impossible situation, it is to "Fail" as early and cleanly as possible.  It would probably be quite easy to not throw an exception and make something work, but the behavior is undefined.  This is doing everything possible to make sure that you don't have a coding bug in your iterator, not just recover from an impossible code corner.

```
// This line is getting the underlying array out from "this" ArrayList   
Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData; 

// I is the current value of your cursor.  Every time you call "next"
// this cursor is being incremented to get the next value
// This statement is asking if your current cursor extends beyond the
// end of the array, if it does then "Something" happened to make the array
// smaller while we weren't looking...
if (i >= elementData.length) 
    // To indicate that the elementData array has changed size outside of
    // our current iterator, throw an exception to the user.
    throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

So, to cause this to happen, you would create an iterator, then reduce the size of the array list, then call "Next".  This should give you a CME

Comment: Can you explain this line here, I couldn't understand what exactly this elementData is doing :
 Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
    if (i >= elementData.length)
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();

Comment: If the length of `elementData` has changed due to a removal in the outer list, `i` might _have been_ a valid index in `elementData` but is now out of bounds, and `elementData[i]` would _now_ throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.  That block of code throws an exception that addresses the actual _cause_ of the issue, namely that the `ArrayList` was modified concurrently with an iteration, rather than the _symptom_ that `i` is now out-of-bounds.

Comment: @ Bill K Thanks for the explanation! But i have one doubt as you said I would have to remove one element and call “Next” to get the above exception. Shouldn’t that be handled during removal of the element i.e. “remove” method. If yes what is the point of again checking it during the “Next”.

Comment: When you remove the element with ArrayList.remove() the implementation doesn't actually "Know" that you are iterating over it--only the iterator knows that.  So the iterator is the one that has to "notice" it and throw an exception.  There is an iterator.remove() method that actually does know and adjusts everything for you after removing the element so that it doesn't throw an exception.